# throw error when attribute is accessed but doesn't exist in object

Tags: javascript

In Python, when I try to access a key in a dictionary that doesn't exist, an error is thrown:

```
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> d['baz']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'baz'
>>>
```

Is there a comparable way to achieve this behavior in Javascript? Would prefer to not use a third-party library.

Comment: Do an explicit check.

Comment: I would like to avoid explicit checks. I have to access this object hundreds of times in my application, so an automated method to throw an error would be preferred.

Comment: You can make a function to do this for you.  Like `function getProp(obj, prop)` and have that throw an error if the property doesn't exist.  Then just use `getProp()` whenever you need to access something.

Comment: If you don't care about compatibility you may use ES6 Proxy objects, and write proxy that throws exception when property is not present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but there is the [`zealit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zealit) node module.
That's using ES6 Proxies.

```js
const zealit = require('zealit')

const ref = { foo: true, bar: undefined }
ref.foo // true 
ref.bar // undefined 
ref.baz // undefined 

const zealed = zealit(ref)
zealed.foo // true 
zealed.bar // undefined 
zealed.baz // throws a ReferenceError
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap it in a function:

```
function get(object, key) {
  if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    throw new Error(`No key ${key}`)
  }
  return object[key]
}

const d = { foo: 'bar' }
const foo = get(d, 'foo') // ok
const error = get(d, 'bar') // throws
```

If you want to check the whole prototype chain, the suggested library solution might be better.